# Expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync doesn't await

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to read a list of hospitals from a file in a React Native project using Expo FileSystem. I want to wait for the list to return so that I can render it on the screen. I can easily get the result in the ".then" block, but I'm struggling to figure out how to wait for the list from readAsStringAsync in the same function. My attempts always return the Promise and not the list, or an "unhandled promise rejection" error occurs. Here is my code:

```
getHospitals = async () => {
        let result = null;
        let content = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'hospitals.json').then(function (data) {
            result = data;
        }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return result;
    }
```

How can I wait for a result from readAsStringAsync?

Comment: You shouldn't use then and catch when using async, await. The point of async await is to get rid of callbacks

Comment: Also your catch syntax is wrong, it should be similar to then

Comment: Extra curly brackets removed from catch. Btw. the target device is an iPad 11.3.1 (iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async`, `await` is replacement for `then`, `catch` callbacks. They are not supposed to be used together.

```
getHospitals = async () => {
    let result = null;
    try {
        result = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'hospitals.json');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm understanding the syntax better and trying your corrections, but I still only get the Promise returned and not the result.

Comment: I used this code and added new state-variable "hosps" and used "this.setState({ hosps: result })" in the try block, instead of returning the result. My component now returns a list.